# NEO4J How to make graph with relationships

Tags: neo4j

I am completely new to NEO4j and using it for the first time ever now for my masters program. Ive read the documentation and watched tutorials online but can’t seem to figure out how I can represent my nodes in the way I want.

I have a dataframe with 3 columns, the first represents a page name, the second also represents a page name, and the third represents a similarity score between those two pages. How can I create a graph in NEO4J where the nodes are my unique page names and the relationships between nodes are drawn if there is a similarity score between them (so if the sim-score is 0 they don’t draw a relationship)? I want to show the similarity score as the text of the relationship.

Furthermore, I want to know if there is an easy way to figure out which node had the most relationships to other nodes?

I’ve added a screenshot of the header of my DF for clarity https://i.stack.imgur.com/BltCJ.jpg. I hope anyone can help me, thanks in advance!

Edit: What I have tried

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///wiki-small.csv' AS line
MERGE (p:Page {name: line.First})
MERGE (p2:Page {name: line.Second})

MERGE (p)-[r:SIMILAR]->(p2)
ON CREATE SET r.similarity = toFloat(line.Sim)
```

Next block to remove the similarities relationships which are 0

```
MATCH ()-[r:SIMILAR]->() WHERE r.Sim=0 
DELETE r
```

This works partially. As in it gives me the correct structure of the nodes but doesn't give me the similarity scores as relationship labels. I also still need to figure out how I can find the node with the most connections.

Comment: can you share the code you have tried?

Comment: Ive edited my original post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question:

> How can I create a graph in NEO4J where the nodes are my unique page names and the relationships between nodes are drawn if there is a similarity score between them (so if the sim-score is 0 they don’t draw a relationship)?

I think a better approach is to remove in advance the rows with similarity = 0.0 before ingesting them into Neo4j. Could it be something feasible? If your dataset is not so big, I think it is very fast to do in Python. Otherwise the solution you provide of deleting after inserting the data is an option.
In case of a big dataset, maybe it's better if you load the data using **apoc.periodic.iterate** or `USING PERIODIC COMMIT`.

Second question

> I want to know if there is an easy way to figure out which node had the most relationships to other nodes?

This is an easy query. Again, you can do it with play Cypher or using APOC library:

```cypher
# Plain Cypher
MATCH (n:Page)-[r:SIMILAR]->()
RETURN n.name, count(*) as cat
ORDER BY cnt DESC

# APOC 
MATCH (n:Page)
RETURN apoc.node.degree(n, "SIMILAR>") AS output;
```

**EDIT**
To display the similarity scores, in Neo4j Desktop or in the others web interfaces, you can simply: click on a SIMILARITY arrow --> on the top of the running cell the labels are shown, click on the SIMILAR label marker --> on the bottom of the running cell, at the right of *Caption*, select the property that you want to show (*similarity* in your case)

Then all the arrows are displayed with the similarity score

[image]

Comment: Thank you Im going to try this out! Could you maybe also help me with the question how I can change the labels of the drawn relationships to be the similarity score (as in the float) instead of just having SIMILARITY as label?

Comment: You're welcome! For your last question, I don't think it's something feasible: I mean, LABELs in Neo4j are a way to define a TYPE of a node/relationship, like a Class in Object-Oriented Programming. It makes no sense to set a Label = 2.41 or to any other similarity score, since in Neo4j these scores represent a property of the relationship, not a type of the relationship. I don't know if I was clear enough, but setting a Label equals to a score makes no sense

Comment: What are the reasons why you want to set similarity scores as labels? Maybe I miss something

Comment: I would like to clearly represent how strong nodes are related by displaying their similarity score in the graph itself if that makes sense, but if you say it is not feasible I might have to look into other options

Comment: Ok, if it's only a visualisation problem, you can simply set what you want to show in Neo4j. I edit my answer to show you how to visualize the similarity scores in Neo4j Desktop. Let me know if it's what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

To the second question:  I think you should keep a clear separation between the way you store data and the way you visualize it. Having the similarity score (a property of the SIMILARITY edge) as a "label"  is something that is best dealt with by using an adequate viz library or platform. Ours (Graphileon) could be such a platform, although there are also others.

We offer the possibility to "style" the edges with so-called selectors like

`"label":"(%).property.simScore"`  that would use the simScore as a label. On top of that you could do thing like

```
"width":"evaluate((%).properties.simScore < 0.500 ? 3 : 10)"
```

or

```
"fillColor":"evaluate((%).properties.simScore < 0.500 ? grey : red)"
```

to distinguish visually high simScores.

Full disclosure :  I work for Graphileon.